# How to highlight text in PDF files in Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-reader

Some pdf readers for windows allow you to highlight and type notes into PDF files. The pdf readers that I've seen for Linux only allow you to read pdfs. Are there any that allow you to highlight text and add notes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [okular](http://okular.kde.org/) for that purpose. Be aware that it doesn't actually change the PDF. The annotations are stored in a separate file and can (only?) be displayed by okular.

[screenshots](http://okular.kde.org/screenshots.php)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [Xournal](http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http%3A%2F%2Fxournal.sourceforge.net%2F) ([article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xournal)).

Comment: Just FYI: This is an old question and the site guidelines have changed since then.  Questions like this, that just seek a list of application names, would be off-topic now.  This link http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers describes how to recommend software in an answer.  In general, an answer should describe how to solve the problem rather than just point to a tool.  Also, link-only answers can become unhelpful if the links break, so the essential information should be included in the answer, with the link for further information and attribution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [Jarnal](http://www.dklevine.com/general/software/tc1000/jarnal.htm) as a rather cool general note taking tool (and its cross platform)?

Comment: Are annotations stored into the PDF?